# See github commits in files of cloned project

Tags: github

I know that you can see the commits and the people that executed these on the github page.

But can you see all the commits and the people responsible for these commits in the files of a cloned project?

For example: Person A clones a project and gives a copy to Person B.
Can Person B simple use git log on the project to see the commits?
Or can Person A only do this?

Comment: have you tried`git log`?

Comment: @igormilla That's an option too! I added some more info to my question.

Comment: when you clone a repo, you get a full copy with all its history. And as long as you include `.git` directory when sharing a copy of a project, everyone else will get all this info too. Try it yourself: clone a repo, and make few copies of it in your PC